# serialize a subclass, then deserialize it back into the subclass

Tags: c++, serialization, polymorphism, deserialization

## Problem Introduction

I want to serialize a `Message` instance to send it over the network, then receive it, and deserialize the data back into an identical `Message` instance, which not a problem.

The problem is that I would like others to be able to subclass the `Message` class, but then deserialization becomes difficult, because I don't know which subclass the serialized data is from, so I don't know which deserialization function to use.

Serialization is easier, because I can create an abstract `serlialize` method that subclasses would have to implement. This way, at runtime, I can just call `Message::serialize()`.

Before the serialization occurs, all I have is a pointer to a `Message` instance. After the deserialization, I would like to have a pointer to the `Message` instance (not a pointer to a subclass of the `Message` class).

I have come up with a few solutions, but I don't particularly like any of them because they seem like it would be difficult to maintain. I would use them if i have to, but I'm wondering if there are other ways.

I am doing this in `C++`.

## Problems I've run into while trying to solve bigger problem

### *1. Identifying which subclass the serialized data is of*

I need to identify which subclass the serialized data is of in order to determine which deserialization function to use. **The following are possible solutions I've thought of so far:**

- **Serialization protocol;** I can make the first byte be a character which can act as a type identifier so I can figure out which subclass it is.

  - This makes me wonder where I would get such a unique identifier from? Is there a way to get a unique identifier for a subclass in C++? perhapse, something similar to Java's `getCanonicalName()`?

### *2. Performing the deserialization*

After determining which subclass the `Message` instance is of, I need to execute the deserilization function, but my immediate solutons are messy. **Here are some possible solutions I've thought of so far that I would like to improve upon, and avoid otherwise:**

- **Big switch statement;** I would identify whuch subclass the message is, then switch on the subclass type, and have a case for each subclass that performs the deserialization. **I would like to avoid this approach for a few reasons:**

  - Whenever one subclasses `Message`, they would have to add a case to the switch statement, which would undesirable, because the existence of the switch statement is not obvious to those subclassing `Message`.
  - It can become a very large switch statement, which decreases readability.
- **Build a map which maps subclass IDs to deserialization functions;** an entry for each subclass of the `Message` class would be inserted into the map, so after receiving the `Message` instance from the network, and determining the subclass type, I can look up the deserialization function in the map, and call it. **There are issues with this solution:**

  - I can't think of a way to force subclassers of `Message` to insert an entry into this map at compile time.

Thanks for reading everything.